# can you convert multiple shapefiles to a single dxf using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, dxf

I would like to create a dxf from several shapefiles using ogr. The only way I can see to do this would be to create the dxf from one file and then convert the others to the same file using the append option. However when I try this I get an error. Here is my statement:

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF E:\test\augusta.dxf E:\test\100yrflood.shp -append
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1: Layer '100yrflood' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
```

Incidentally, I also have columns called 'layer' and 'color' which are standard cad fields that I have populated and would like to carry over to the dxf. The layer field translates but the color field doesn't, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'Color' not created.
```

Can anyone help?